# Update two conditions only if both conditions are met

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2014

I would like to update a query if two conditions are met. What's happening in my code is, the code is updated if either one of them are met. Not if both are met at the same time.

```
    var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE [Truck Table] 
                                  SET [TruckID] = @TruckID, 
                                      [PlateNumber] = @PlateNumber 
                                WHERE [Condition] <> 'Good' AND 
                                      [MaximumVolumeLoad] <= 10", Con)
```

The code updates a cell even if the condition is good, but the maximum volume load is less than or equal to 10. What I want is, it only updates the Cell if the condition is not Good and the Maxvolumeload is <10.

Comment: Please provide some testdata. Your query is ok. I gues it is because you have null value that you dont handle properly

Comment: Your query has a small typo. You say you want `and the Maxvolumeload is <10.` yet you typed `AND [MaximumVolumeLoad]<=10`. Do notice the `<=` instead `<`

Comment: It's functional, but it doesn't get both of the conditions at the same time. When I tested it. It updated the table that has a condition of "Inactive" and a maximumvolumeload of 9 as well. It tests the conditions separately and not as one.

Answer (score 0):

Code looks OK, it's mostly because of parenthesis :

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE [Truck Table] 
                              SET [TruckID] = @TruckID, 
                                  [PlateNumber] = @PlateNumber 
                              WHERE ([Condition] <> 'Good' AND 
                                    [MaximumVolumeLoad]<10)", Con)
```

Comment: So what parenthesis changes here?

Comment: Why are the parantheses needed?

Comment: It's functional, but it doesn't get both of the conditions at the same time. When I tested it. It updated the table that has a condition of "Inactive" and a maximumvolumeload of 9 as well. It tests the conditions separately and not as one.

Comment: That is not possible @D.Trump123 . It will definitely, 100%, check both conditions.

Comment: @D.Trump123 : Check for case-sensitivity as stated in another answer. That will be the likely cause.

Answer (score 0):

your script looks good, try debugging it, check the **sql** variable; try the script in SSMS

```
var sql = "UPDATE [Truck Table] SET [TruckID] = @TruckID, [PlateNumber] = @PlateNumber WHERE [Condition] <> 'Good' AND [MaximumVolumeLoad]<=10";
var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, Con)
```

Comment: It's functional, but it doesn't get both of the conditions at the same time. When I tested it. It updated the table that has a condition of "Inactive" and a maximumvolumeload of 9 as well. It tests the conditions separately and not as one.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems ok if it is case-insensitive.

```
 var cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE [Truck Table] 
                            SET [TruckID] = @TruckID, 
                                [PlateNumber] = @PlateNumber 
                            WHERE UPPER([Condition]) <> 'GOOD' 
                                 AND [MaximumVolumeLoad]<=10", Con)
```

Comment: It's functional, but it doesn't get both of the conditions at the same time. When I tested it. It updated the table that has a condition of "Inactive" and a maximumvolumeload of 9 as well. It tests the conditions separately and not as one.

Answer (score 0):

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [Truck Table] SET [TruckID] = @TruckID, [PlateNumber] = @PlateNumber WHERE [Condition] <> 'Good' AND [MaximumVolumeLoad]<10", Con)
```

You only needed to remove the equal sign from the second condition in the where clause. Done above for u.

Comment: It's functional, but it doesn't get both of the conditions at the same time. When I tested it. It updated the table that has a condition of "Inactive" and a maximumvolumeload of 9 as well. It tests the conditions separately and not as one.

Answer (score 0):

There's no issue, only the small mistake at greater than or equal at second where clause. Make is  [MaximumVolumeLoad]<10 if you want less than 10 values.

Answer (score -1):

Try running your command in Sql independently, see if it works at all then debug your app and check for